# Как переставить только одну ось. 60000 28 28 > 28 28 60000

Tags: python, numpy, матрицы

Нужно перевсти 60000 28 28 в 28 28 60000. На примере с mnist. В оригинале 60000 28 28, если менять через .T  то картинки тоже переворачиваются. Через .reshape, картинки не получаются.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
a = np.moveaxis(a, 0, -1)
```